# Inserting values to mysql database and retrieving them to insert to another table

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to insert values to mysql database table called pointofcontact and then retrieve the primary key called pocid to insert to another table called students.

Somehow my code always return the pocid to be 0 and i have no idea why. Gladly to get some help. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is my code:

```
$query="insert into pointofcontact(Username,Password,FirstName,LastName,ContactNumber,EmailAddress,Address,Gender,Status,BackupContactNumber,ProfilePic) values ('$username','$password','$firstname','$lastname','$mobilenumber','$email','$address','$gender','Normal','$backup','$attch')";
    if($con->query($query) === TRUE)
    {
        $query2="select POCID from pointofcontact where username= '$username'";
        $result2=$con->query($query2);
        if($result2 ->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $pocid = $row2['POCID'];
                $query3= "insert into student(StudentFirstName, StudentLastName, Allergies, NRIC, POCID) values ('$cfirstname','$clastname','$callergies','$cnric','$POCID')";
            }
            if($con->query($query3) === TRUE)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but you might want to look into using a trigger to do this.  Either that, or you will have to wrap your insert and select in a single transaction.

Comment: Is the 0 is adding to the table? or it showing wrong value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it should do what you need:

```
// assuming proper validation and escaping is completed...

if($con->query("INSERT INTO pointofcontact (Username,Password,FirstName,LastName,ContactNumber,EmailAddress,Address,Gender,Status,BackupContactNumber,ProfilePic) VALUES ('$username','$password','$firstname','$lastname','$mobilenumber','$email','$address','$gender','Normal','$backup','$attch');"){
    $POCID=$con->insert_id;
    if($con->query("INSERT INTO student (StudentFirstName, StudentLastName, Allergies, NRIC, POCID) VALUES ('$cfirstname','$clastname','$callergies','$cnric','$POCID');")){
        // Pass
    }else{
        // Fail
    }
}else{
    // Fail
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your database table design for POCID column. When you created that table you must add it as primary key and auto_increment ...

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (id int primary key auto_increment,....)
```

If you already did this then, use mysqli_insert_id() to get the last inserted id.

Comment: May be thats why it is always adding 0 to table

Comment: I know. It's already been done. Able to get the pocid from my website application that is coded via c# but not able to get this information via php.

Comment: Then store last inserted id to a variable and then get the values as per this id..

Comment: How do i go around using mysqli_insert_id()?

Comment: After inserting the record into database use $id = mysqli_insert_id(); then select the data with where id = $id

Comment: do i need to put the con inside of the code ? e.g $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);